# How to replace a single cell in google refine from multiple numbers in parentheses to a comma

Tags: regex, openrefine

How can I change

```
Alabaster (1)   
Albertville (1)   
Auburn (4)   
Bay Minette (1)   
Bayou La Batre (1)   
Bessemer (3)   
Birmingham (9)
```

Into

```
Alabaster ,   
Albertville ,   
Auburn ,   
Bay Minette ,  
Bayou La Batre ,   
Bessemer ,   
Birmingham ,
```

Using GREL and Regex in Google Refine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the contents of the list are in `value`, the following should do what you want:

```
value.replace(/\(\d+\)/, ",")
```